unable to request an API enabled with fastapi-microsoft-identity using @requires_auth
I have enabled Authentication on fastapi using Azure EntraID App Registration using fastapi-microsoft-identity but needed support on how the api call can be made using the Bearer token.
Here is the API code for same
    from fastapi import APIRouter,Request
    from fastapi_microsoft_identity import AuthError,requires_auth,validate_scope
    import fastapi
    from fastapi.exceptions import HTTPException
    from pydantic import ValidationError
    from utills.config import AppConfigs
    
    
    poc_router = APIRouter()
    scope = "access_api"
    
    
    @poc_router.get("/add/{num1}/{num2}")
    @requires_auth
    async def add_with_auth(request:Request,num1:int,num2:int):
        try:
            validate_scope(required_scope=scope,request=request)
            return num1+num2
        except AuthError as ae:
            return fastapi.Response(content=ae.error_msg, status_code=ae.status_code)
        except ValidationError as ve:
            return fastapi.Response(content=ve.error_msg, status_code=ve.status_code)
        except Exception as x:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=403,detail=f"Failed with Excetion--{e}")

Error:

IDW10201: No scope or app permission (role) claim was found in the bearer token

here is the code I have used to extract jwt token and passing in Authorization header but facing an issue with scope.
from utills.config import AppConfigs
import subprocess,os,json,requests
def get_ad_token():
    curl_cmd = [
    "curl",
    "-X","post",
    f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{AppConfigs.TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token",        
    "-d", "grant_type=client_credentials",        
    "-d", f"client_id={AppConfigs.CLIENT_ID}",        
    "-d", f"client_secret={AppConfigs.CLIENT_SECRET}",        
    "-d", f"scope=api://{AppConfigs.CLIENT_ID}/.default"
    ]
    res=subprocess.run(curl_cmd,capture_output=True,text=True)
    access_token = json.loads(res.stdout)
    return access_token["access_token"]

Please help me in getting proper access token that can be sent to api with correct scope
microsoft oauth API is only allowing scope /.default when I'm passing the scope I defied i.e "access_api" it's complaining that scope in invalid

The error

No scope or app permission (role) claim was found in the bearer token

usually occurs if the access token doesn’t contain any roles or scope claim.
As you are making use of Client credential flow, you need to grant application type API permissions so that the access token will contain the role claim.
To resolve the error, create the app roles like below:


Grant Admin consent:

For a sample, I generated access token via Postman by using below parameters:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
grant_type:client_credentials
scope:api://XXX/.default


When I decoded the token, roles are present:

If you want to pass scope created in Expose an API (that is delegated permissions) tab like below, then you need to make use of interactive flow to generate the access token so that scp claim will be present in the token.

Reference:
DW10201: Neither scope or roles claim was found in the bearer token. custom web api core - Stack Overflow by Carl Zhao
